# Move Existing git Repository into One Repository with Orphan Branch

Tags: git

I was reading online about git and the suggestion is to have a git repository per project. Currently my  setup follows that rule, but recently the number of projects I have is increasing (= number of repositories are increasing) and I would like to move common projects into one repositories each under orphan branch (kind of categories them).

For example, if I have `P1` and `P2` repositories which have histories, what I would like is to create a repository `P` with 2 **orphan** branches `P1` and `P2` and transfer history from `P1` and `P2` repositories to the corresponding branches in `P` repository.

I was wondering if someone can show me (git command) on how to transfer history `P1` and `P2` to `P` orphan branch.

Thank you,

Comment: Why do you think it is preferable to have a single project with multiple orphan branches rather than many projects? (Just curious here)

Comment: I don't know *why* you would *want* to do that, but note that in Git, the history *is* the set of commits. Each commit points to its parent(s), so that the history can be drawn as a Directed Acyclic Graph. If you have two repositories with no relationships between their commits and you fetch one repository's commits into the other repository, the result is two disconnected subgraphs. This is the same result as creating a new orphan branch and making commits on it: the resulting total graph is made up of two disjoint subgraphs.

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you asked you can do in repository `P`

```
git remote add P1 urlToP1
git remote add P2 urlToP2
git fetch --all
```

You will find all the branches of P1 and P2 as `P1/branchName`. You can then create local branches.

The key point this is in the [git fetch doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch)

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more other repositories, **along with the objects necessary to complete their histories**.

Those objects include commits. Since the two original repositories `P1` and `P2` do not share any commit, you end up with two separate graphs.

Answer (score 0):

Great suggestion **Francesco**. While doing `git fetch` works, I would constraint it a bit by specifying the `source:target` branches, and using your **local** `P1` and `P2` repositories. I'd also like to complement your answer in order to fully cover the original question.

## The solution

Let's say you want to move the `master` branches of `P1` and `P2` into two new **non existent** branches on `P`, named `p1` and `p2`, respectively
(do not create the p1 and p2 branches in advance).

1. Add the remote repositories on P

   `git remote add P1 ~/path/to/P1
   git remote add P2 ~/path/to/P2`

   > You could also specify an url to the repo instead of the path.
   >   i.e. `git remote add P1 urlToP1`
2. Fetch **only what you need!** (the n flag excludes tags, you may want to take it out)

   `git fetch -n P1 master:p1
   git fetch -n P2 master:p2`

   > syntax: `git fetch -n <remote> <sourceBranchOnP1>:<targetBranchOnP>.`
3. Remove the remote repositories

   `git remote remove P1
   git remote remove P2`